# How do I prove that $f'(0)$ doesn't exist for $f(x) = 3x^2 + x - \frac{1}{x} + \frac{2}{x^2}$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

So, what I did was:
$f'(x) = 6x + 1 + \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{4}{x^3}$. Approaching it from $0^-$ will give me $f'(0^-) = 0 + 1 + \infty - (-\infty)$ which means that $f'(0^-)=\infty$. But, I don't know how do I find the value of $f'(0^+)$. If I substitute in, it'll give me $\infty-\infty$ which is undefined. If I say that $undefined \neq \infty$ so $f'(0)$ doesn't exist, is that right?

I also checked WolframAlpha and it said that $f'(0^+) = -\infty$. How do I get to that result?

Comment: What is $f(0)$? In order for the derivative to exist at a point the function has to be continuous and, in particular, it has to be defined at the point.

Comment: @PeterForeman Indeed, however the function is defined at the origin, it cannot be continuous there. So the value of $f$ at the origin is not as important as the fact that the singularity there is not removable.

Answer (score 2):

By your work the domain of $f'$ is $x\neq0$, which says that $f'(0)$ does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

To find the limit of $f'(x)$ as $x\to 0+,$ note that for $x$ near $0,$ we may ignore the polynomial part, and all positive constants, so that we want to consider how $$g(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x^3}$$ behaves as we approach $0$ from above. Note that in this case, we have that $x^2>x^3,$ which implies $$\frac{1}{x^2}<\frac{1}{x^3},$$ so that $g(x)<0$ for $0<x<1.$ Now both quantities separately become $+\infty$ at $0+,$ so that whatever limit they approach will be negative. To find that combine them to get $$\frac{x^3-x^2}{x^5},$$ which is a candidate for L'hopital. Or better still, simplify to get $$\frac{x-1}{x^3},$$ which approaches $-1/0,$ or $-\infty.$

---

However, a straightforward way to show that $f$ is not differentiable at the origin is to note that $f(0)=\pm\infty,$ so that the function *cannot* be continuous there. It then follows that it cannot have a derivative at the origin.